# How to use JFormattedTextField to allow only alphabets?

Tags: java, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I searched for the solution everywhere, but all I found solutions allowing only numbers, alphanumeric (using `DocumentFilter`).

But, I need to allow alphabets only and I intend to use `JFormattedTextField` due to some advantages.

So, how to use `JFormattedTextField` to allow only alphabets (a-zA-Z) (no space, punctuation, letters)!

Comment: is the JFormattedTextField able to receive a variable number of alphabets? or its a fixed number?

Comment: variable number of alphabets!

Answer (score 0):

Since the number is variable, and if i'm not wrong the JFormattedTextField uses masks for fixed length of digits, will be more easy to use an litener for change text event and validate the text in the element removing unallowed characters.

Something like that:

```
JTextField f = null;

f.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener()
{
  @Override
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
  {
    validateInputText();
  }

  @Override
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
  {
    validateInputText();
  }

  @Override
  public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
  {
    validateInputText();
  }
});
```

Comment: And what if I copy some text having numbers, spaces and paste it in the field. This will not work in that case.

Comment: Updated my asnwer to solve this. Now, when the text changed doens't matter the way its changed you'll be notified, so you can handle all the validation you need.

Comment: Yes, but what is the use, if data already has been updated. `DocumentListener` methods are fired after document has been updated.

Comment: Yeah, then you remove the data you don't want

Comment: That is possible but it will be too much work and will not be the best solution. As I mentioned need to use `JFormattedTextField` capabilities.

Comment: Well, i don't think is too much work because you can reutilize your code if you need for more than 1 field, and to replace the text you don't want you can use a simple regex like [^a-zA-Z] it will replace everything that isn't a alphabet, i'm not sure but i guess the JFormattedTextField can't handle variable lenght of characters for a mask

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions, I think the best solution is to extending `DocumentFilter` class.

Here is the code:

```
class AlphabetFilter extends DocumentFilter {

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
            AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(fb, offset, string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", ""), attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
            String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]+", ""), attr);
    }

}
```